# KDE-Plasma does not look like it should

Tags: unity, gnome, kubuntu, multiple-monitors, kde

Ubuntu version: 20.04

I have been using RHEL for long time form server purposes (mostly only text), but I'm newbie in Ubuntu for Desktop daily usage.

Previously I had original gnome and installed KDE-Plasma. I'm uncertain which tutorial I used. But I remember well that there was an issue with monitor drivers, or something like that. Monitor was not displaying well. I barely could run the first command on this tutorial.
https://computingforgeeks.com/install-kde-plasma-desktop-on-ubuntu-linux/.

After that... KDE-Plasma looked beautiful and in the same way that it appears in all videos and pictures. Especially the "files" app with the terminal panel, Etc. I also had several additional applications, like an alternate terminal app (but original terminal was still there too), Etc.

Then I formatted my machine (long story).

I reinstalled. I had gnome and I customized it to look like Mac Catalina. I used Gnome Tewaks and dconf-editor for that.

About KDE-Plasma. There are several ways to install it, and tutorials are not clear about differences.

FIRST. I installed this: https://computingforgeeks.com/install-kde-plasma-desktop-on-ubuntu-linux/. This is the same which fixed monitor issue previously, but...

The login screen changed in a VERY different way this time, saying Kubuntu, and not Ubuntu anymore. And the desktop was like with gnome still there. "Files" apps wasof my disk  the same than gnome, it only added a task bar in the bottom, and a menu bar in the top. No several menus in the bottom left corner, nor the logo for KDE. Nothing about the additional KDE-Plasma apps that I saw previously.

I restored a Clonzilla image of my disk from before this KDE-Plasma installation.

SECOND: I installed again KDE-Plasma, installing first "tasksel" and then "kde-plasma-desktop". This time login screen was similar to the first time I installed KDE-Plasma, but the desktop looks exactly the same, mostly like gnome.

Is it possible to have gnome cusomized like Mac Catalina, and KDE-Plasma in the way KDE-Plasma should be, in the same way I had it the very first time?

What should I do?

Comment: It may be a good idea not to install GNOME and KDE in the same installation. Decide whether you want to use GNOME or KDE (or something else) and fresh install the appropriate flavor of Ubuntu.

Comment: Yes it is, but it's very unclear to me what you did and what your issue is (what should KDE Plasma look like?  according to what?  Pure upstream? as RHEL is usually behind in packages so if comparing it to RHEL you're likely comparing to what it used to look like, not what it does today).  I've been a fan of multiple desktops on my systems for as long as Ubuntu has existed... but there are drawbacks to doing that. You only mention a single tutorial, but I'd suggest trying to stick with official tutorials when possible...  You also tagged 3 desktops, but didn't even mention the third you tagged

Comment: Hi Archisman, The fact to have both desktops and alternate my day to day work between them, is to finally chose the best one for me. So, my objective having them installed at same time, is precisely to chose only one and have only one, in the future.

Comment: Hi Guiverc,
My current KDE looks like a mix of Gnome and KDE. That's the issue. RHEL is nothing about my current situation. I just mentioned RHEL as prior frame of reference.